# python pandas selecting values based on age

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Pandas and have zero luck so far.

My data frame looks like this:

```
                        A           B        C          D
time                
2013-07-19 14:54:03     1354.85     92.20   1453.44     7746.56
2013-07-19 14:56:02     1348.30     44.60   1399.83     7800.17
2013-07-19 14:58:02     1285.76     33.93   1325.31     7874.69
...
2013-12-16 14:24:02     1114.74     136.59  1254.04     7945.96
2013-12-16 14:26:03     1180.76     65.39   1248.59     7951.41
2013-12-16 14:28:03     1015.98     126.96  1147.68     8052.32
```

This data gets updated very frequently and I would like to be able to select all values in the last 24 hours, or last week, or last month, etc.

My current workaround is to pull the data from a database using a query such as this:

```
24_hour_data = ('select time, A, B, C, D from \
     agg where time >= datetime(\'now\', \'-24 Hours\', \'localtime\')')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you don't have to deal with timezones:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
yesterday = now + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'  #     fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %T' if you want more precision.

df.ix[yesterday.strftime(fmt):now.strftime(fmt)]
```

With your example:

```
In [17]: now = pd.datetime(2013, 7, 20)  # since thats when the data is from

In [18]: yesterday = now + datetime.timedelta(days=-1)

In [19]: df.ix[yesterday.strftime(fmt):now.strftime(fmt)]
Out[19]: 
                         B        C        D
time                                        
2013-07-19 14:54:03  92.20  1453.44  7746.56
2013-07-19 14:56:02  44.60  1399.83  7800.17
2013-07-19 14:58:02  33.93  1325.31  7874.69

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Also have a look at the [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) library to replace the `datetime` part. It's fantastic for these sorts of things.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the code, but I receive a KeyError: '2012-12-16' message.  Should I be using a Series?

Comment: That should work on a DataFrame. Make sure that your index is a [`DatetimeIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). You shouldn't get a `KeyError` when you use `.ix` on a DatetimeIndex with a `:` in the slice. At worst it will return an empty DataFrame.